# What is the recommended dosage of 5000 mcg Vitamin B-12

Tags: nutrition, dosage, b-12-supplements

I brought these vitamin B12 capsules from Costco

[image]

The supplements panel says its okay to take one tablet daily

[image]

but I am worried since 1 tablet has a whooping 83333% or as much as 833 times the daily value. To put it in perspective, one of these tablets should be good for 2 years! Is it really okay to take one of these tablets daily? What is the recommended dosage? I am vegetarian and consume dairy products sparingly

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of vitamin scams. I don't know the answer offhand but I wouldn't take 83333% of much of anything.

Comment: Maybe remove the comma separator in 83,333? In Europe, this is equivalent to 83.333 (83 percent and a third). There might be some misconception...